# Cast from '(key: Any, value: Any)' to unrelated type '[String : Any]' always fails

Tags: json, swift3

I am working on a project and have reached a stage where I want to display data from a web service in a table view. My json data is in dictionary format and I am taking loop for fetching the data from dictionary by using key but it's getting the warning. So, please help me for this type of warning.

My loop is:-

```
let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! NSDictionary

 for eachFetchedRestaurant in fetchedData {

     let eachRestaurant = eachFetchedRestaurant as! [String : Any]
     let restaurantName = eachRestaurant["restName"] as! String
     let restaurantImage = eachRestaurant["restaurant_image"] as! String

     self.fetchedRestaurant.append(Restaurants(restaurantName: restaurantName, restaurantImage: restaurantImage))
     }
     print(self.fetchedRestaurant)
```

Getting warning on this line:-

let eachRestaurant = eachFetchedRestaurant as! [String : Any]

```
 Cast from '(key: Any, value: Any)' to unrelated type '[String : Any]' always fails
```

Thanks in advance for helping!!!

Answer (score 1):

Since JSON  response is array of `(key, value)` format, so your fetch data should be of `[[String:Any]]` format. Here is the updated code.

```
let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [[String:Any]]

 for (key,eachFetchedRestaurant) in fetchedData {

     let eachRestaurant = eachFetchedRestaurant as! [String : String]
     let restaurantName = eachRestaurant["restName"] as! String
     let restaurantImage = eachRestaurant["restaurant_image"] as! String

     self.fetchedRestaurant.append(Restaurants(restaurantName: restaurantName, restaurantImage: restaurantImage))
  }
  print(self.fetchedRestaurant)
```

Comment: In this line,   for (key, eachFetchedRestaurant) in fetchedData   getting an error    Expression type '[[String : String]]' is ambiguous without more context. Red line is shown around fetchData.

Comment: then try to use '[[String:Any]]' . Updated solution.

Comment: Same error is getting, Expression type '[[String : Any]]' is ambiguous without more context. Now, what can I do?

Comment: My fetchedData is dictionary and when I want to convert it to array. Either getting warning or error or app crash(thread bad expr). So, provide me sufficient solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` in Swift, use native types.

You are applying array related enumeration API to a dictionary. The dictionary related API is

```
for (key, eachFetchedRestaurant) in fetchedData
```

---

You've got two options:

1. `fetchedData` is indeed expected to be **dictionary** then cast

   ```
   let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String:Any]
   ```

   and use the mentioned enumeration API
2. (the more likely one) `fetchedData` is expected to be an **array** then you have to cast

   ```
   let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [[String:Any]]
   ```

Comment: Can you tell me the code which I can write inside the loop?

Comment: What is the actual type of `fetchedData`?